# How to remove leading slash "/" if angular app is deployed at "example.com/home" url?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I have an angular app which is served through a CloudFlare worker. The app is served on `example.com/home` route.

When I go to the `https://example.com/home` URL in browser the app is loaded correctly but the URL is automatically changed to `https://example.com/home/`.

The app is built with `--base-href=/home` option.

I blame angular. How do I disable this behavior?

Here goes the routing configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: can you show us your app's routing configuration? (in the root module)

Comment: here is an angular issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21003

Comment: Is this on an Apache server? `mod_dir` automatically redirects your requests to the same URL with a trailing slash. https://serverfault.com/questions/817014/drop-trailing-slash-in-apache-for-directory